# "convert" text box to text area with sliding animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, positioning

I'm trying to make a textbox with an expand arrow that, when clicked, removes the text box and replaces it with a larger textarea with a nice sliding animation using jQuery. The problem is, the relatively positioned arrow on the right and the label on the left slide down with the textbox as it expands. I've been trying various combinations of `vertical-align`, `display`, `padding` and other CSS properties to try to keep them at the top all without avail. Interestingly, the design works in Firefox, the label and arrow staying where I want them, but not in Chrome or IE. You can see the work [here](http://sha1.in/expand.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `vertical-align: top;` to your textarea and don't change it when you do your animation. I tried it in Chrome debugger and it works fine.

Also, why are you swapping an `<input type="text" />` with a `<textarea>`? Why not just have `<textarea>` from the beginning, just give it a small height?

**UPD.** Assign `vertical-align: top;` to your `<input>` element as well so the label and the arrow stay at the same place when you swap it to textarea. Use `top` or `margin-top` to nudge them down a little bit if you need to.

*//I don't have IE at hand so currently can't help you with that... What's happening in IE after suggested changes?*

Comment: That kind of works, but it still appears somewhat strangely. The textbox appears too far down relative to the label and arrow. As to why I'm not using a textbox to begin with, it's because of the way a textbox handles text overflows and new lines pasted in

Comment: Works with a little bit of `position:relative` magic on the label and arrow. Thanks for the help.